# Nav overlay doesnt close after clicking on a nav item

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on my portfolio website, but have a problem with my navigation overlay. When I open it, it works just fine. When I click on an item in the overlay it does navigate to it on the page, as it navigates to a part of the home page, but doesn't close the navigation overlay. Clicking on the X does still close it so there is no problem there. It jst doesn't close after clicking on a nav item

I'm using vanilla javascript for it with toggleClass, but I cant figure out why it doesn't close.I have tried removeClass aswell, but no luck there

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-toggler').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open').show;
    $('.top-nav').toggleClass('open').show;
  });
});
```

```css
.top-nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100vh;
  z-index: 50;
  background-color: #16162d;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  transition: all 650ms cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
}

.nav-list {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  margin: 0 2rem;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: 'The Historia Demo', sans-serif;
  font-size: 5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.nav-link:hover,
.nav-link:focus {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #00ffde, #0003fd);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.top-nav.open {
  top: 0;
  border-radius: initial;
}

.menu-toggler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5rem;
  right: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1500;
  transition: transform 650ms ease-out;
}

.menu-toggler.open {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.bar {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00e4ff, #0003fd);
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: .8rem;
}

.bar.half {
  width: 50%;
}

.bar.start {
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: transform 650ms cubic-bezier(0.54, -0.81, 0.57, 0.57);
}

.open .bar.start {
  transform: rotate(-450deg) translateX(.8rem);
}

.bar.end {
  align-self: flex-end;
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 650ms cubic-bezier(0.54, -0.81, 0.57, 0.57);
}

.open .bar.end {
  transform: rotate(-450deg) translateX(-.8rem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-toggler">
  <div class="bar half start"></div>
  <div class="bar "></div>
  <div class="bar half end"></div>
</div>
<nav class="top-nav">
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#experience" class="nav-link">Experience</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

For all the code here is my codepen
https://codepen.io/Triable/pen/BayqOWO

Comment: Why do you expect it to close? The function handler is bound to `$('.menu-toggler')` which is the `<div>` in the upper-right corner. Only clicking on that element runs the function. You could give your other nav items the same class or you need to bind a different function to those elements.

Comment: This is the working codepen link https://codepen.io/rohitgoyal7/pen/wvBYERZ

Comment: Also note that your use of `.show` is not actually doing anything in this instance. For one, all your visibility changes and animation are being handled by your css when the classes are toggled. Second, the next time you use them, be aware that they should have parenthesis `()` after them (`.show()` instead of `.show`), even if you pass no parameters, or they won't work anyway. https://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add another event handler for click the `.top-nav`:

```js
var $toggler = $('.menu-toggler');
var $topNav = $('.top-nav');

function toggle() {
  $toggler.toggleClass('open');

  $topNav.toggleClass('open');
}

$toggler.on('click', toggle);

$topNav.on('click', toggle);
```

```css
.top-nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100vh;
  z-index: 50;
  background-color: #16162d;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  transition: all 650ms cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
}

.nav-list {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  margin: 0 2rem;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: 'The Historia Demo', sans-serif;
  font-size: 5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.nav-link:hover,
.nav-link:focus {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #00ffde, #0003fd);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.top-nav.open {
  top: 0;
  border-radius: initial;
}

.menu-toggler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5rem;
  right: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1500;
  transition: transform 650ms ease-out;
}

.menu-toggler.open {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.bar {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00e4ff, #0003fd);
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: .8rem;
}

.bar.half {
  width: 50%;
}

.bar.start {
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: transform 650ms cubic-bezier(0.54, -0.81, 0.57, 0.57);
}

.open .bar.start {
  transform: rotate(-450deg) translateX(.8rem);
}

.bar.end {
  align-self: flex-end;
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 650ms cubic-bezier(0.54, -0.81, 0.57, 0.57);
}

.open .bar.end {
  transform: rotate(-450deg) translateX(-.8rem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-toggler">
  <div class="bar half start"></div>
  <div class="bar "></div>
  <div class="bar half end"></div>
</div>
<nav class="top-nav">
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#experience" class="nav-link">Experience</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```